# Multi-Device Hybrid Apps with angularjs on Android: $location.path() not working

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, location, visual-studio-cordova

I've got a strange problem in a very simple project using Multi-Device Hybrid Apps on Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 with Apache Cordova and AngularJS. I've set up routing with the ngRoute module, defined a div with the ngView directive and just want to navigate to another page by code using the angular $location service.

My call looks like this:

```
$location.path('/home');
```

The routing (and module definition) is set up like this:

```
var app = angular.module('tk', ['ngRoute']);    

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

   $routeProvider.when('/home', {
      templateUrl: '/app/views/home/home.html',
      controller: 'homeController'
   });

   $routeProvider.when('/login', {
      templateUrl: '/app/views/login/login.html',
      controller: 'loginController'
   });   
});
```

When the code is executed the view doesn't change! The same code works perfectly well in Ripple but I can't get it to work in the android debugger.

I'm using android 4.4.2 - API level 19 on ARM (armeabi-v7a).

When the call to `$location.path('/home')` is executed I can see in the debugger that the property absUrl of the $location service changes its value from "file:///android_asset/www/index.html" to "file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/home" but that's all. No navigation to the view takes place.

Am I missing something completely?

edit 1:
In Java Script Console i noticed the following messages:

```
Failed to load resource File: home.html, 
Line: 0, Column: 0 
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. File: cordova.js, 
Line: 1128, Column: 17 
Channel not fired: onPluginsReady File: cordova.js, 
Line: 1121, Column: 21 
Channel not fired: onCordovaReady File: cordova.js, 
Line: 1121, Column: 21
```

Actually i'm not using any cordova plugins right now. Just pure Angular stuff. 
The call to $location.path() obviously fails because the resource couldn't be loaded.

But why did this succeed in Ripple?

Comment: Have you tried removing the leading `/`? so `home` instead of `/home`. I am not familiar with how angular works in this regard but I do know that android takes some issue with pathing.

Comment: Hi Dawson! Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately removing the slash didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when then a project runs on Ripple, it should functionally work on other targets as well.

However, Android and iOS are both **case-sensitive** platforms. One solution is to go through your source code and figure out if there are any references to files, scripts or resources that may not follow case-sensitivity.

Comment: Hi Priyank, thank you for your hint. 

In my demo project i've got only one link and every reference to this link is written in lower case. 
All the other angularjs stuff (databinding, event handling) works as far as i can tell but only navigation just won't navigate! 

If i don't use angularjs routing and just hardcode a url by setting window.location this would change the page but that's not what i want.

Comment: @MarkusS Did you resolve this? I am having a similar issue. It works in ripple but not on an android device

Comment: @osiris355: Well at least it's now working with the new version of Cordova Integration in VS2015 Preview in combination with the Hyper-V-Based Android Emulators.

Answer (score 0):

I spent several hours wrestling with this exact same issue myself.. Dawson Loudon was close with his path observations.. but it is not the /home that needs to be changed .. it is the templateUrl: that should be app rather than /app.

```
   $routeProvider.when('/home', {
      templateUrl: '/app/views/home/home.html',
      controller: 'homeController'
   });
```

should be:

```
   $routeProvider.when('/home', {
      templateUrl: 'app/views/home/home.html',
      controller: 'homeController'
   });
```

I don't know why but the android devices don't like the first '/' for the url. I guess taking the root by default. Shame the guys at Ripple don't quite emulate it correctly.